# Django - accessing related models in custom model function

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    b = models.ManyToManyField(ModelB, related_name = 'abs')

class ModelB(models.Model):
    x = models.IntegerField()

    def foo(self):
        self.abs.all() ...
```

I would like to access in the foo method of ModelB all the ModelA's in the ManyToMany relationship - I have tried this using the above but it says that 'abs' is not a field of ModelB. How can I fix this?

Many thanks

Comment: What you have shown would work. You'll need to post your actual code and the traceback.

Comment: pylint says that the instance of ModelB has no 'abs' member

Comment: Don't rely on pylint. Does the code actually work?

Comment: Something like that? def foo(self): return ModelA.filter(b=self).all() ?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `return` statement at `foo` method. Please change `self.abs.all()` by `return self.abs.all()`.

Answer (score -2):

All what you need is:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    class Meta:
       app_label = 'app'
    b = models.ManyToManyField(ModelB, related_name='abs')

class ModelB(models.Model):
    class Meta:
       app_label = 'app'
    x = models.IntegerField()

    def foo(self):
       return self.abs.all()
```

I check this and its work.

Comment: How is this different from the question? Adding `app_label` doesn't change anything.